# how do I use this Css on an element

Tags: html, css

I've been given the following as a template for some css:

```
.customError { …... }

.customError p { …… } 
.customError p strong { ….. }
```

for the first I'd simply do something like `<p class="customError"....` but how would I assign the second 2?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: To help interpret the link in this context, the second selector applies to `p` elements that are descendants of elements of the `customError` class, while the third selector applies to descendants of *those* elements.